# Is there a way to code sign ad-hoc iOS apps for longer than 7 days in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, development, developer-program

I know, on Xcode, you can create an iPhone app, and test it on your own phone via USB cable, but this expires after 7 days.

I want to create a swift app just for my iPhone and not have it expire so quickly. What are my options?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Free developer membership apps require resigning to be functional after 7 days.

Paid developer membership apps expire after 1 year. You can also submit an app for testing to TestFlight which signs apps for 90 days. You can purchase a developer membership at https://developer.apple.com

If your device is jailbroken, you can resign your apps with a free developer account for as long as you wish, on device with **Extender: Reloaded**, available from the repo http://repo.incendo.ws.

[image]

Comment: is there any other way to accomplish this rather than paying 100$ every year? Can I make the profile on a URL and download it again every 7 days?

Comment: Not really @IainMoncrief - the code signing process is the same - just the expiration date changes.